# Strange date issue with PHP strtotime

Tags: php, mysql, date, strtotime, date-conversion

I'm trying to store some dates in my datebase (MySQL). But I got a strange conversion error:
This is my piece of PHP code:

```
$fechanac=mysql_real_escape_string(($_POST["fechanac"]));
echo "<h1>{$fechanac}</h1>";
$fechanac=date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $fechanac)));
echo "<h1>{$fechanac}</h1>";exit();
```

---

See the following three example, trying with (01/01/1900, 01/01/1901 and 01/01/1902).

**OUTPUT:**

01/01/1900

1970-01-01

---

01/01/1901

1970-01-01

---

01/01/1902

1902-01-01

Somebody know why happens this? And how to fix it? I need to insert in my DB, possible dates of living persons. Thanks for reading.

Comment: If you're using 32-bit PHP, then your timestamp is limited to the range of a signed 32-bit timestamp (the number of seconds before/since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC), giving the valid range of a timestamp from Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC

Comment: welcome to a variant of the [y2k problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem)! =)

Comment: Interesting, is there any way to accomplish what I want to do with a 32-bit machine? It should be possible to record people 125 years and newborns, for example.

Comment: MySQL/Maria has a DATETIME column type, which can store dates that you supply as strings. If possible, simply use those instead.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans But I can use datetime without taking into account the hours minutes and seconds? Moreover, it is a problem with PHP, not yet put them in MySQL

Comment: if you don't care about the hours/minutes/seconds you can use the simpler DATE datatype, which uses YYYY-MM-DD format. See the [date, datetime and timestamp documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html)

Comment: Use [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects in PHP rather than unix timestamps, or upgrade to a 64-bit version of PHP

Comment: @MarkBaker, Hmmm, what you think it is okay to make a parsing of the string to convert the variable posted in the format I want?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans What would have happened if they didn't find a solution to Y2K? Would we be sitting here right now talking via the internet?

Comment: That's not even a hypothetical question. In any scenario where humans are smart enough to invent computer science to the degree in which Y2K can manifest, we're smart enough to find a solution. The only reason it was a "problem" is because we're also lazy and simply assumed the bad code we wrote would not be around long enough to matter.

Answer (score 0):

Date stored!

```
$fechanac=mysql_real_escape_string(($_POST["fechanac"]));
echo "<h1>{$fechanac}</h1>";
$datearray=explode("/",$fechanac);
$fechanac="{$datearray[2]}-{$datearray[1]}-{$datearray[0]}";
```

Comment: Solve the problem to "add" the date, but how about calculate age?

Comment: just ask mysql/maria to do the calculation for you, because it can.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I have stored "1899-01-01" in date column of my mysql DB. If I do the following code: $years=floor((time() - strtotime($fechanac)) / 31556926); Where $fechanac is "1899-01-01". It returns "44"... Corresponding to 1970 y2kproblem.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans can you tell me a better way? I do it with php, because if the years are zero, I calculate monthly, if it is zero, I calculate the weeks, if zero, I calculate the days old

Comment: select the DATE from mysql, which gives you a yyyy-mm-dd string, split on '-' so you have data[0] for year, data[1] for month and data[2] for days, then just use something like [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) to do the computation instead of rolling it yourself>

Answer (score 0):

I know it's and old post, but maybe this late answer can help others:

The ***[DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)*** correctly manages dates older than 1970. So forget the use of `date()` and evolve to `DateTime`:

```
$fechanac=mysql_real_escape_string(($_POST["fechanac"]));
echo "<h1>{$fechanac}</h1>";

$fechanac=(new DateTime($fechanac))->format('Y-m-d');

echo "<h1>{$fechanac}</h1>";exit();
```